# regarding like query operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

For the below data (well..there are many more nodes in the team foundation server table which i need to refer to..below is just a sample)

```
Nodes
------------------------
\node1\node2\node3\
\node1\node2\node5\
\node1\node2\node3\node4\
\node1\node2\node3\node4\node5\
```

I was wondering if i can apply something like (below query does not give the required results)

```
select * from table_a where nodes like '\node1\node2\%\'
```

to get the below data

```
\node1\node2\node3\
\node1\node2\node5\
```

and something like (below does not give the required results)

```
select * from table_a where nodes like '\node1\node2\%\%\'
```

to get

```
\node1\node2\node3\
\node1\node2\node5\
\node1\node2\node3\node4\
```

Can the above be done with **like** operator? Pls. suggest.

Thanks

Comment: did you try select * from table_a where nodes like '\node1\node2\%\%'

Comment: What results DO these queries give?

Comment: @THEn: This query gives me \node1\node2\node3\node4\node5\ as well.

Comment: Please note, if you say LIKE '\node1\node2\%\' it is effectively saying 'give me a slash followed by anything followed by another slash. That will return every row in the table. because \node3\node4\node5\ still fits the criteria of \%\ (i.e. it starts and ends with a slash)

Comment: @Dave Colwell: Is there a way to write the query to get intended results?

Comment: a small amount more information. If your node counts are single digit (i.e node1 - node9) then you could use the '\node1\node2\node[0-9]\' to find 'node1\node2\node3\ or 'node1\node2\node4\'. Working on another solution. will post below when complete

Comment: how about something like    
select  * from  nodes where len(node)-len(replace(node,'\','')) between 2 and 4 and node like 'node1\%'

Comment: @THEn, that is quite smart, +1.

Comment: @Dave Colwell: This is just some dummy data. TFS table has alpha-numerics names for the nodes. So it will not contain just digits or single digits.

Comment: i think THEn's solution will work for you. just use where len(node)-len(replace(node,'\','')) = 4. The number(4) is representative of the number of '\' characters in your node string you wish to find. so 4 will find \node1\node2\node3\ and 5 will find \node1\node2\node3\node4\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to combine two terms, LIKE and NOT LIKE:

```
select * from table_a where 
   nodes like '\node1\node2\%\' AND
   nodes NOT like '\node1\node2\%\%\'
```

for the first query, and a similar solution for the second.  That's with "plain SQL".  There are probably SQL Server specific functions which will count the number of "\" characters in the column, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this would work (basically just eliminating the last backslash):

```
select * from table_a where nodes like '\node1\node2\%\%'
```

**EDIT**

You could also try this:

```
select * from table_a where 
      nodes like '\node1\node2\%\' or
      nodes like '\node1\node2\%\%\'
```

Comment: edited my question to better reflect the intended results. This query will give me \node1\node2\node3\node4\node5\ as well.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: In that case, you could only accomplish what you want with an `OR` expression of two different `LIKE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use the delimiter to get the resutls.
it is unclear what you are actually trying to get, but you could use the

```
substr
```

function to either count or find the position of the delimiter '/' character.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but it appears that the problem is still open.  Could it be that the backslashes are escaping the wildcard meaning of the percent signs?  And the backslash n could be getting interpreted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sql-server know a wildcard for a single character?

```
 select * from table_a 
   where nodes LIKE '#node1#node2#node_#';
        nodes        
---------------------
 #node1#node2#node5#
 #node1#node2#node3#
```

I testet this on postgresql, where it is hard to insert a backslash, which is the reason why I replaced them with #.

Here is another possibility - negate more than one backslash (# used for my convenience):

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 
WHERE (nodes LIKE '#node1#node2#%#' 
  AND NOT nodes LIKE '#node1#node2#%#%#');
```

On postgresql there is too the possibility to match against patterns, with SIMILAR TO, or ~:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 
WHERE nodes SIMILAR TO '#node1#node2#[^#]*#';
        nodes        
---------------------
 #node1#node2#node5#
 #node1#node2#node3#
```

[] encapsulates a group of alternatively allowed characters, for example [aeiou] would be a lowercase vocal. But when the caret is the first sign in the brackets, the sign(s) are negated so [^aeiou] would mean anything but a lowercase vocal, and [^#] means anything but a #. 
The asterix behind that expression means that the preceding sign can occur as often as you like, 0 to million times. (+ would mean at least one times, ? would mean 0 or 1 times).

So '#node1#node2#[^#]*#' means '#node1#node2#', followed by anything but a hash, 0 or single or multiple times, and then, finally a hash.